# Optimize large dictionary for reading in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dictionary

I have a list of number-string related couples, there are 22k of them. (it is a MAC address vendor list).

In my code, I'm searching the Vendor name by first three bytes of MAC address.

I know, I can use a dictionary, even array use is possible, but there is the need to initialize the dictionary every time I run the program, but the program uses only small amount of translations (under one percent to the items in dictionary) and initialisation of the dictionary takes a significant amount of time when the program runs.

Can you imagine any other method? In old VB6 there was possibility to read Binary file and seek the records, which would be good enough for me, because I will load only values that I actually need.

I'm prefering an in-project solution - so there is no external file with data. I am trying to use code like:-

```
Vendors.add("00125A","Microsoft Corporation") 
'... this in another 22000 times '
Vendors.add("00124E","XAC AUTOMATION CORP.")
```

Comment: Read in the dictionary in a background thread, if you do not need it right after the start of the program

Comment: It is console application, so I can load it in another thread, but I cannot start other operations until the dictionary load is complete.

Comment: Load the dictionary by chunks in the background, every time a chunk is loaded pass it to a queue to process it.

Comment: _In old VB6 there was possibility to read Binary file and seek the records_ -> in `.Net` you can read Binary file too

Comment: @null, your comment leads me to another one possible solution: I can load the dictionary and do the other work in separate threads and show the result just after both threads are done. It is not as effective as my desired solution where I do not need to load strings I do not need, but thank you for that.

Comment: @Fabio, yes, but I can seek bytes, not records as far as I know, like it was in VB6

Comment: If reading just 22k data takes a noticeable time, perhaps there is something wrong with the dictionary initialization. If you showed us the code then maybe we could help you fix it.

Comment: code is pretty simple:
Vendors.add("00125A","Microsoft Corporation")
... this in another 22000 times
Vendors.add("00124E","XAC AUTOMATION CORP.")

Comment: It is running 4 or 5 seconds, but, it isnt question. Im wondering about a technique that allows me not to initialize a ton of variables that will die without any use in few seconds.

Comment: In addition it is not reading, only adding to dictionary.

Comment: Since your 'record' contains a string, ie a variable length field I wonder if VB6 could do any better than sequentially read until it found the nth record. You can do that here too..

Comment: 22k is not a lot of data.  I dont know what a "significant amount of time" is but perhaps if you showed the code someone could offer some optimization ideas

Comment: @JanVojtěchVaníček Earlier versions of VB (I think it was in VS2008; I reported the problem and it was fixed) had problems creating large things in code from literals. Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @JanVojtěchVaníček I edited your question to make it clearer that you are currently populating the dictionary from literals in code. If you don't like my edit, please feel free to edit it further or roll it back.

Comment: I don't say that VB6 was better, but trying to illustrate the functionality I'm needing. And yes - variable string length could be problem as well. For now, I break initialization procedures into four separate threads and it is much better, but it doesnt solve the main problem - by my opinion it is not efficient kind of solution to this.

Comment: Im using VS2010 .NET 4

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the best course of action should be for you or if this will actually help you but..

You seem to seek a way to seek&read a certain record from a structured file.

For this you can define a class the encapsulates the record fields and also the access methods.

Here is an example. On my machine it creates, stores 22k+ records and seeks a few all in around 20ms. Otoh doing 100 random seeks takes 3.5 seconds, obviously because it always start at the begiining. Doing a sequential search is rather fast again..

Of course total time will depend on your machine and how many records you will seek&read..

Here is a record class that holds a byte, a long and a string:

```
class aRecord
{
    byte aByte { get; set; }
    long aLong { get; set; }
    string aString { get; set; }

    public aRecord() { }

    public aRecord(byte b_, long l_, string s_)
    { aByte = b_; aLong = l_; aString = s_; }

    public void writeToStream(BinaryWriter bw )
    {
        bw.Write(aByte);
        bw.Write(aLong);
        bw.Write(aString);
    }

    public void readFromStream(BinaryReader br)
    {
        aByte = br.ReadByte();
        aLong = br.ReadInt64();
        aString = br.ReadString();
    }

    static public aRecord readFromStream(BinaryReader br, int record)
    {
        int r = 0;
        aRecord  rec = new aRecord();
        br.BaseStream.Position = 0;
        while (br.PeekChar() != -1 & r <= record  )
        {
            rec.readFromStream(br);
            r++;
        }
        return rec;
    }

    static public aRecord readFromStream(BinaryReader br, string search)
    {
        aRecord rec = new aRecord();
        while (br.PeekChar() != -1 )
        {
            rec.readFromStream(br);
            if (rec.aString.Contains(search)) return rec;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I tested like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss,ffff") + "  init ");

List<aRecord> data = new List<aRecord>();

Random rnd = new Random(9);

int count = 23000;
for (int i = 1000; i < count; i++ )
{
    data.Add(new aRecord((byte)(i%128), i, "X" + rnd.Next(13456).ToString()));
}

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss,ffff") + "  write ");

string fileName = "D:\\_DataStream.dat";

FileStream sw = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(sw);

foreach(aRecord r in data)
{
    r.writeToStream(bw);

}
bw.Flush();
sw.Close();
bw.Close();

FileStream sr = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(sr);

List<aRecord> data2 = new List<aRecord>();
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss,ffff") + "  begin search");
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    aRecord  rec = aRecord.readFromStream(br, "911");
    if (rec != null) data2.Add(rec);
}
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss,ffff") + "  done. found " + data2.Count);


Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss,ffff") + "  seek ");

aRecord ar = aRecord.readFromStream(br, 0);
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss,ffff") + " 0 ");

aRecord ar1 = aRecord.readFromStream(br, 1);
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss,ffff") + " 1 ");

aRecord ar2 = aRecord.readFromStream(br, 13000);
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss,ffff") + " 13000 ");

aRecord ar3 = aRecord.readFromStream(br, 23000-1);
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss,ffff") + " 23000 end ");

br.Close();
sr.Close();
```

Your titel is concerned with *optimizing a `Dictionary`*. This depends on what the uses will mainly be: Reading or Writing? If you read a lot in the Dictionary, best create a `SortedDictionary`. If you need to create many mor entries than you expect to read a nomal `Dictionary` would be better..

..and there are evne more collection classes, but the first thing is to **find out what the true bottleneck** is. The above seek&read routine will not waste time inserting the data into a `Dictionary` but simply discard them until the right record is found. I have also added a search method which continues after each hit at the same position. Expanding the class to suit your own needs is rather simple.

27,2208  init

> 27,2297  write
>
> 27,2438  seek
>
> 27,2438 begin search
>
> 27,3097 done. found 38
>
> 27,3097 0 end
>
> 27,3097 1 end
>
> 27,3457 13000 end
>
> 27,4037 23000 end

Comment: Is it really faster to go multiple times thru the Binary files than load once all content to Dictionary? In small amount of queries in such big file yes - so thanks for inspiration!

Comment: Well that really depends on your usage! The seek always went though n records and is geared for direct access, not reading in ranfges. The search was just a simple example for a single pass access. - If you know which records you seek and/or in which order they are you can write a custom-tailored access method, which may not need to do multiple passes.. You could feed in a List of search strings or a range of numbers etc..

Comment: Note the the search example went through all records and found and returned 39 records in just 50ms. - What will your usage be? Maybe I can provide some more inspiration?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the data as a resource and then use an instance of `ResourceManager` to retrieve the value.

```
var rm = new ResourceManager(baseName, assembly);
string vendor = rm.GetString(macAddress);
```

To create the resource file (without having to key it into Visual Studio) you can make an executable that reads your source file and creates a .resources file from it:

```
string path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(outputPath, "..\\MyData.resources"));

using (IResourceWriter rsxw = new ResourceWriter(path))
{
    foreach (var x ...)
    {
       rsxw.AddResource(x.name, x.value);
    }
    rsxw.Close();
}
```

Include this MyData.resources file in your project and it will be compiled in as a resource.

Comment: That sounds good, but if the resource manager is using collection, it will work the same way durning application initialization. I will give it a try.

Comment: It uses a stream internally to read the data from the assembly file.